# Managing 3rd party accounts created with my Google Account?

Tags: google-account

Many services offer the ability to "Sign up using Google," such as Stack Exchange. Other examples are Quizlet, Yelp, etc. Essentially, you can create a user account using the credentials of your Google Account.

Now I am looking to delete my Google Account, and clear all associated services which I had utilized with said account. How should I do this?

Is there a place where I can "unlink" my Google Account to these 3rd party services?

Thanks

Comment: The Google Account Help Center has several related articles. Search it, and show what you found, and why they didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [permissions section](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) in your Google account settings.

You'll have a list there of all the apps you logged in to, with your Google account.

[image]

---

Related: [I have a little list I made](https://github.com/arieljannai/AuthorizedAppsInServices), of links to the connected apps / permissions section in some popular websites, such as the mentioned link for Google.

Answer (score 0):

Such connections must be removed separately from both sides – there's no automatic "link".

#### Consumer

Each service has a record of your Google account ID and possibly OAuth token. You need to use the service's own website to change the authentication method (e.g. add a regular password or another OAuth provider).

For StackExchange websites, go to your profile → "Edit Profile & Settings" → "My Logins".

Unlinking the Google account at services **will not** revoke the authorization stored by Google.

#### Provider

Google also records the authorization you've given to each service. You can view those under "My Account" → ["Apps with access to your account"](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) (this includes websites) and remove them, although of course if you delete the account all authorizations will go away.

Removing the authorization at Google **will not** delete your profiles on 3rd-party services. (For example, deauthorizing Stack Overflow and trying to log in again will simply show the authorization prompt again, and will bring you back to the same Stack Overflow profile.)

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying. This made things very clear.

I do wonder tho, say if I deleted my Google Account, and my Stack Exchange account still exists. How would I log into my Stack account afterwards? Or is it "lost" and inaccessible, but still there?

Comment: Yes, if Google was the _only_ login mechanism, then the SE account becomes inaccessible. (You can email SE support team about finding some ways to regain access. [This thread might have more tips.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/49849))